# Why does PHP give Permission Denied errors when writing file?

Tags: php, macos, permissions

I'm running XAMPP 1.8.2 with the default PHP 5.4.19 on OS X 10.8.5.
My PHP application is supposed to have read/write access to a certain local directory, but it's not working.  For testing, I distilled it down to a very simple script:

```
<?php
$file = "/Volumes/RAID/AT_RISK/copra/uploadedfiles/file.txt";
$current = "hello world\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Warning: file_put_contents(/Volumes/RAID/AT_RISK/copra/uploadedfiles/file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP-1.8.2/xamppfiles/htdocs/filetest.php on line 4

I've tried this command, but it doesn't help.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Volumes/RAID/AT_RISK/copra/
```

Here you can see the permissions for yourself:

```
$ pwd
/Volumes/RAID/AT_RISK/copra/uploadedfiles
$ ls -l
total 32
-rwxrwxrwx  1 elliott  staff  7 Oct 12 22:31 file.txt
```

Comment: Might be a dumb idea, but you could try adding www-data to the folder/file itself and that may work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the "/Volumes" notation.  Apparently php cannot read from that file.txt with fileperms(), but it can read from /etc/passwd just fine.

Comment: Sorry for like crazy late response but I ment change the group to www-data like chgrp www-data file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. Although the folder had correct permissions, the volume itself (/Volumes/RAID) was 700. Problem solved.